# How can I plot 3-D system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

If I have three equations nonlinear. I need to see the behavior around (0,0).
How do I plot the three-dimensional system? Thank you in advance.

[image]

I try to use this code

```
ParametricPlot3D[
 {2 x^2, -y^2, z^2}, 
 {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}
 ]
```

Comment: If you solve these differential equations (e.g. `DSolve[x'[t] == 2 x[t]^2, x, t]`) you will get solutions with a constant in each of them. To find the constant, you must have some initial condition. Otherwise you can't plot the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your differential equation describes a vector field (velocity field) that you may display e.g. using SliceVectorPlot3D:

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{2 x1^2, -2 x2^2, 
  3 x3^2}, "CenterPlanes", {x1, -.1, .1}, {x2, -.1, .1}, {x3, -.1, \
.1}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: Velocity Field]

You see, that e.g. a particle coming from below from `{0.1,-0.1,-0.1}` with velocity `{0.02,-0.02,0.03}` will turn into the direction `{1,-1,0}` and will never reach the x3==0` plane.

Comment: Shouldn't it be -1 x2^2?

Comment: Thank you Daniel Huber, How do I make the shape move in place until I see the back parts

Comment: @user74531 Simply click on the graphics and move the mouse.

Comment: @Lee Yews you are right, thank you.